# AngularJS Glitches

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm developing a MEAN stack application. I have a very rare glitch that makes my site unusable.

I have make video to illustrate what is happening.

Things to take notes about:

The glitch is solved when I hover over the tab name, or when I move to another chrome tab and I return here.

Could you tell me if you have seen something like this before?

Thanks in advance for your answers and your time.

Here is the video link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0QWPtcmBoNIaVVGMjhubnhQZVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've seen similar glitches when the client's browser plugins are conflicting with the page. Do you have anything else competing with Angular to modify/render the DOM?

Comment: That could be a million of reasons - starting from incorrect implemented directives, bad integration with some 3rd-party components (not calling `$apply`) and ending, as mentioned, some extensions. Try to reproduce this behaviour in JSBin or Plunker.

Comment: I have disabled all the browser plugins, and the result is the same. The began with a bootstrap tab plugin. In firefox it works perfectly.